# kendo ui grid show cross button after filter

Tags: user-interface, filter, kendo-ui, grid

[image]

I am using kendo Grid. When i am filtering with combo box on a column, then the filtering working but the filtering cross button right side of the filter button is not showing.To see this i need to drag column of the grid. How can i see the cross button when i am filtering.

```
 {
                                                field: "BranchId",
                                                type: "number",
                                                title: "Branch",
                                                width: "200px",
                                                editable: true,
                                                nullable: true,
                                                hidden: false,
                                                values: Branches,


                                            },
```

Comment: I resolve my problem after update the kendo script.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give a custom width size to the columns

Comment: custom width size fit with my combobox in chrome but in Firefox it is ok.